# Java format double value with german locale

Tags: java, formatting, format, locale, number-formatting

I have the double value 1400.0 and now I want to format this value into 1.400,00 in Java.

currently I do:

```
double doubleValue = 1400.0    
String pattern = "0.00";
DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN)
format .applyPattern(pattern);
// will be 1400,00 and not 1.400,00
String formattedValue = format.format(doubleValue);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I replaced the code with the detail implementation

Comment: Chnage your pattern to `format.applyPattern("#,##0.00");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
String pattern = "#,##0.00";
```

This pattern tells a DecimalFormat to add the grouping character to the given number.

Edit: Originally I wrote this with zeros, but this would actually create extra zeros for small numbers. Use the `#` pattern where you don't want initial zeros.

Comment: @JanKoester That's because your original question was about `NumberFormat`, not `DecimalFormat`. I edited to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double doubleValue = 74637.96;
    Locale locale = Locale.GERMAN;
    String string = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).format(doubleValue);
    System.out.println(string);
  }
}
```

and the output will be:
74.637,96

[GermanFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mmec.png)